# C++ macro definition without a pound sign

Tags: c++

Here is a c++ header file I found somewhere else.

```
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(cv::Mat)
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

/** Serialization support for cv::Mat */
template <class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, const ::cv::Mat& m, const unsigned int version)
{

    size_t elem_size = m.elemSize();
    size_t elem_type = m.type();

    ar & m.cols;
    ar & m.rows;
    ar & elem_size;
    ar & elem_type;

    const size_t data_size = m.cols * m.rows * elem_size;
    ar & boost::serialization::make_array(m.ptr(), data_size);
}

};
}
```

My question is: What does the following code mean?

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(cv::Mat)
```

Is it a macro definition? Then where is the pound sign "#"?

Answer (score 1):

In short words, **it's a macro**. `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(my_class)` is the macro, which is short for the following free serialize function template:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template<class Archive>
    inline void serialize(
        Archive & ar,
        my_class & t,
        const unsigned int file_version
        ){
            split_free(ar, t, file_version); 
    }
}}
```

Also note that `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE` must be used outside of any namespace. Check out [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html) for further info.

Comment: You could even refer to it as a "call to the BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE macro".  While macros aren't exactly functions, they behave similar to them.

Comment: Can you give me some reference of detailed explanation of such usage of macros?

Answer (score 0):

macros to split serialize functions into save & load functions